# is it possible to use a computers (would be) audio output as a stream?

Tags: windows, linux, audio, lan, streaming

I have two machines on a local area network (xp box and xubuntu box) and I want audio from both machines to be played from the same set of speakers.  The problem is, the xubuntu machine doesn't have any sound output.  There is no onboard sound card and all expansion slots are pci-x, so short of buying a pci-x sound card my only option for playing sound is to route audio through LAN to my xp computer.

I already have a program that will let me play music on one computer from another's speakers, but I am trying to set up a stream so that games and internet sound can be heard.  Is it possible for me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PulseAudio for this.  It has networked sound built in.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while and some googling but I finally got audio working.